# ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here in "./docker-compose.yml" + Jeroen-G / alpine-artisan

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose

I use this source https://github.com/Jeroen-G/alpine-artisan for create local environment  laravel 7.4

I run docker-compose up -d --build, and he return
ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
in "./docker-compose.yml", line 11, column 18

My Dockerfile

```
FROM jeroeng/alpine-artisan:web7.4
```

My docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - .:/www/html

  db:
    image: percona:5.7
      environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:-secret}
        MYSQL_DATABASE: my_database
        MYSQL_USER: jeroen
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:-secret}
      volumes:
        - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql:rw
      ports:
        - 3306:3306

  queue:
      image: redis:5-alpine
      ports:
        - 6379:6379

  horizon:
    image: test_app
    command: php artisan horizon

volumes:
  mysql-data: # nothing necessary here, let Docker manage the storage
```

how to fix it?

Comment: Under `db:`, `environment:`, `volumes:`, and `ports:` are indented one step more than `image:`; you need to delete two spaces from the start of these lines.

Comment: Thank! This solved my problem!